# Console closes without reason C#

Tags: c#, sockets

I am having a problem with my application. I was building a client/server based application. But my console closes when I execute this line of code:

```
            response = Console.ReadLine();
```

My full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace Server
{
    class Program
    {
        private static byte[] _buffer = new byte[1024];
        private static List<Socket> _clientSockets = new List<Socket>();
        private static int SERVERPORT = 5555;
        private static Socket _serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SetupServer();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        private static void SetupServer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Setting up server...");
            _serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, SERVERPORT));
            _serverSocket.Listen(100);
            _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
        }

        private static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket socket = _serverSocket.EndAccept(AR);
            _clientSockets.Add(socket);
            Console.WriteLine("Client conntected");
            socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), socket);
            _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);


        }

        private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
            int received = socket.EndReceive(AR);
            byte[] dataBuf = new byte[received];
            Array.Copy(_buffer, dataBuf, received);
            string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataBuf);
           Console.WriteLine("Text received: " + text);
            string response = string.Empty;
            if (text.ToLower() == "get time")
            {
                response = Console.ReadLine();
                //after this line it closes the server for some reason?
                Console.WriteLine(response);
            } else
            {
                response = "Invalid request";
            }


            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response);
            socket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), null);
            socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), socket);

        }

        private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            try {
                Socket socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
                socket.EndSend(AR);
            }
            catch {

            }
            //It gets alot of NullReferenceExceptions. It does work this way but I dont trust it.
        }


    }
}
```

If I change the `response = Console.ReadLine();` to `response = "Any Text";` it works perfectly. I am totally clueless. I would really appreciate a solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You call `Console.ReadLine()` in the callback. Isn't that async, meaning that you cannot block it via `ReadLine()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because after getting line at console your Main method exits - it also waits for Console.ReadLine(). To fix, you can do:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SetupServer();
    while (Console.ReadLine() != "exit")
        ;
}
```

Will close only when you type "exit".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are looking at the wrong line I think. Read from this if-statement: if (text.ToLower() == "get time")

Comment: look at your Main method which _also_ uses Console.ReadLine(), and when _any_ line is typed - Main method will exit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Your main thread is in `Console.ReadLine()` waiting for input. Then you want another thread to also read input from console. This cannot work obviously.

You have to either make your main thread read console and send the input to the other thread or find a way to halt the main thread without using `Console.ReadLine()`.

You could try setting up an `AutoResetEvent` and calling its `WaitOne()` on the main thread to make it hand indefinitely as a test.